# Chr(32) from word document appearing in a VBA selected range, however, cannot exclude this from the selection through standard methods

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an ActiveDocument.Range from my word document that is 7 characters long.

```
debug.Print len(replace(.Range.Text, Chr(32),""))
7
```

From what I can tell through the use of the asc char, it is made up of ASCI 32 characters (space), and one 13 character to end.

```
debug.Print asc(mid(.Range.Text,1,1))
 32 
debug.Print asc(mid(.Range.Text,2,1))
 32 
debug.Print asc(mid(.Range.Text,3,1))
 32 
debug.Print asc(mid(.Range.Text,4,1))
 32 
debug.Print asc(mid(.Range.Text,5,1))
 32 
debug.Print asc(mid(.Range.Text,6,1))
 13
```

I wish to exlcude all white spaces from this string to then check if it has any remaining valid characters left, however, I was unable to detect these characters

I first tried to use the Trim function, however, this returns a length of 7 still with no white space trimmed. Fair enough, this might be because there's only white space in the string

```
Len(Trim(.Range))
```

To verify the character, I tried to search for a space or search for a chr(32) inside the .Range.Text. Both of these returned to 0

```
debug.Print instr(.Range.Text, " ")
 0 
debug.Print instr(.Range.Text, chr(32))
 0
```

Odd... so I tried to replace either a chr(32) or a " " from the text, but still came up with the same results

```
debug.Print len(replace(.Range.Text, Chr(32),""))
 7 
debug.Print len(replace(.Range.Text, " ",""))
 7
```

I'm lost as to were to go next in trimming this space out / processing the length of this string without the white space.

Comment: What's the output of `debug.Print len(replace(.Range.Text, mid(.Range.Text,1,1),""))`  and `debug.Print asc(mid(.Range.Text,7,1))`?

Comment: If `len(replace(.Range.Text, Chr(32),""))` returns 7, there are 7 non-space characters in your text.

Comment: If it is possible you should update your answer to show the word range (with formatting chars) and also the word range (with formatting chars) with field view on.

Comment: It may not solve the problem, but you should really be using AscW and ChrW instead of Asc and Chr.